# Making a quiz on python with while loops and IF statements

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm trying to ask a question on python, so that if the person gets it right, they can move onto the next question. If they get it wrong, they have 3 or so attempts at getting it right, before the quiz moves onto the next question. I thought I solved it with the below program, however this just asks the user make another choice even if they get it correct. How do I move onto the next question if the user gets it correct, but also gives another chance to those that get it wrong?

```
 score = 0
    counter = 0
    while counter<3:
        answer = input("Make your choice >>>>  ")
        if answer == "c":
            print("Correct!")
            score += 1
        else:
            print("That is incorrect. Try again.")
            counter = counter +1

    print("The correct answer is C!")
    print("Your current score is {0}".format(score)
```

Comment: you need to `break` after the `score += 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're stuck in the loop. So put

```
counter = 3
```

after

```
score += 1
```

To get out of the loop.

```
score = 0
counter = 0
while counter<3:
    answer = input("Make your choice >>>>  ")
    if answer == "c":
        print("Correct!")
        score += 1
        counter = 3
    else:
        print("That is incorrect. Try again.")
        counter = counter +1

print("The correct answer is C!")
print("Your current score is {0}".format(score)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're stucked in the loop, a cleaner way of solving this is using the function break as in:

```
score = 0
counter = 0

while counter < 3:
    answer = input("Make your choice >>>> ")
    if answer == "c":
        print ("Correct!")
        score += 1
        break
    else:
        print("That is incorrect. Try Again")
        counter += 1

print("The correct answer is C!")
print("Your current score is {" + str(score) + "}")
```

I would like to highlight a few things about your original code.

1- Python is case sensitive, the code that you gave us will work as long as you type 'c' in lowercase.

2- The last line of I edited it so it would correctly print the score.

For further reading about control flow and the function break try python docs here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html